# Media Independent Interface

Tags: voltage, current, clock, ethernet, phy

I'm reading about the PHY, MAC and the MII interface.

I understand that the MDI interface from the RJ-45 to PHY will be 10Mbps, 100Mbps or even higher to 1Gbps.

But when this data signals move to the MAC, the MII clock speeds are 25MHz, RMII - 50MHz, GMII - 125MHz, RGMII - 125MHz and SGMII is 625MHz.

I just want to understand what would be the speed of the data transfer from PHY to MAC using this MII/RMII/xMII interface as the clock speed is 25MHz, 50MHz and so on.

Like, how to understand this: The speed between the RJ-45 and PHY is 100Mbps or higher, but what is the speed between PHY to MAC and how does the speed increase from PHY to MAC?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly is the question but for example 100Mbps is transmitted as 100 Mbps, the MII/RMII just sends multiple bits in parallel so clock is lower. Is this what you ask?

Comment: Yes, could you please tell me on what would be the data rate in the MII interface. Like, for fast ethernet, the data transfer from PHY to MAC, is also at 100Mbps? Because, the clock rates are 25MHz, 50MHz and so on? So, could you please tell me the correlation between the clock speed and the data transfer speed from PHY to MAC on the MII Interface?

Comment: Since you are already reading about it, what have you figured out yourself so far? I bet the datasheets of chips you have previously linked to must contain this information, if they describe MII and RMII operation.

Comment: I checked but was not able to find the reference of this information in the datasheet. Could you help ?

Comment: If you're sending 1 bit at a time at a rate of 25MHz, then your bit rate is 25Mbps. If you're sending 2 bits at a time at a rate of 25MHz then your bit rate is .... 50Mbps! Now, how many parallel bits at a time get sent over the MII interface between MAC and PHY?

Comment: At least the datasheet of your Micrel PHY explains it in the section called "RGMII interface".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed between PHY and MAC also will be the same as between PHY and RJ45.

In MII, clock speed is 25MHz, but 4 parallel data signals are used between PHY and MAC. So the speed meets 100Mbps(25x4- 4bit data is transmitted or received on each clock cycle).

In RMII, the clock speed is doubled to 50MHz and parallel data lines are reduced to 2. so in each clock cycle 2bit data transmitted or received. So the effective speed is 100Mbps (50x2).

In GMII, the clock speed is increased to 125MHz and data line increased to 8bits. So 8bits are transmitted or received on each clock cycle. The speed reaches to 1000Mbps(125x8).

In RGMII, the data lines are reduced to 4bits and clock speed remains same. But data is sampled on both rising and falling edge of the clock. meaning in each clock cycle 2 bits are transmitted or received on one data line, so with 4 data lines 8 bits are transmitted or received on each clock cycle and meets 1000Mbps speed (125x2x4)

In SGMII, the clock speed is increased to 625Hz and number of dat line is reduced to one. Data is sampled on both rising and falling edge of the clock. So the speed on the link reaches 1250Mbps. But the SGMII uses 8b/10b encoding (encodes 8 bit data to 10bit symbols). So the actual throughput will be 1000Mbps (625x2x8/10).